# Explanation about residues of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, meromorphic-functions

Let $f $ be meromorphic in $\mathbb C $ with three simple poles (in $\mathbb C $), that have residues $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$. If $f $ is holomorphic at infinity, what is the form of $f$? Assuming that the zero at infinity is of order $2$, what is the relation between $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$?

I don't understand well what does this exercise ask: I know that under these conditions, $f $ must be a rational function with a zero of order $1$ in $\mathbb C $, namely $$\frac {z-a} {(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}$$ for some complex numbers. This should be an answer to the first answer, but what is the relation between the residues? Thank you

Comment: to say that $f$ has a zero of order 2 at $\infty$ is to say that $\frac{1}{f}$ has a pole of order 2 at $\infty$. But your $1/f$ only has a single simple pole, unless we can say something about the values of the residues in the numerator and denominator

Comment: 3 simple poles at $b,c,d$ and double zero at $\infty$ means $f(z)=r\frac {z-a} {(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}$. The residue at $b$ is $\frac{b-a}{(b-c)(b-d)}$ that it is $=a_1$ is one more equation

Comment: @ziggurism why does my function $\frac 1 f $ have a simple pole at infinity? It is a pole of second order

Comment: Thank you @reuns